# How can I make user input case insensitive in an HTML Form in Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a custom function on Google Sheets that allows the user to see how much they have spent on an expense.

Here is the example output:
[image: Example output]

The HTML sidebar:

[image: HTML Sidebar]

Here is the JavaScript function:

```js
function perCentBrand(brand){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var total = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function(row){
    total+=row[1];
    if (row[6]==brand){sum+=row[1]}
  })
  var val = "You spent a total of " + sum + " on " + brand + " out of " + total + " ." + " Additionally, " + (sum/total)*100 + "%"  + " of your income has been spent on " + brand; 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(val)
}
```

And here is the HTML form code:

```html
    <form onsubmit="runFunc()">
      <input class = "u-full-width " id="brand" type = "text" placeholder="Enter brand name">

    <div class="u-full-width" style="display:flex; justify-content: center">
      <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

I have read about the `toLowerCase()` and the `toUpperCase()` methods but I am unsure if these should be included to make the user input case insensitive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function perCentBrand(brand){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var total = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function(row){
    total+=row[1];
    if (row[6].toLowerCase() == brand.toLowerCase()){sum+=row[1]}
  })
  var val = "You spent a total of " + sum + " on " + brand + " out of " + total + " ." + " Additionally, " + (sum/total)*100 + "%"  + " of your income has been spent on " + brand; 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(val)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean "make user input case insensitive" regarding your if-statement, so I would control for case there `if (row[6].toLowerCase()==brand.toLowerCase()){sum+=row[1]}`.